# traefik - simple modification of URL

Tags: traefik

I want to modify the endpoints of my URL, while it goes from traefik to one of my containers. What I want is this.
My URL looks like this - http://backend/asd   and it should point to one of my containers with different endpoint like this - http://asd/dfg
What I tried -

```
  asd:
    image: asd
    container_name: "asd"
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=asd"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:backend;PathPrefixStrip:/asd,PathPrefix:/dfg"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=80"
```

But this didn't work. Any suggestions are welcome.
Regards,
Ashutosh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you including a [Traefik](https://traefik.io/)-docker-image in your docker-compose, like so?

```
traefik:
  image: traefik
  ports:
    - 8080:80
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  command:
    - "--docker"
```

For your path-replacement "/asd" -> "/dfg", Traefik's [ReplacePath-modifier](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/replacepath/) should do the trick. This following docker-label is the only, you will need:

```
labels:
  - "traefik.frontend.rule=Path: /asd; ReplacePath: /dfg"
```

Having this setup, doing

```
curl http://localhost:8080/asd
```

should return the HTTP-response from your "asd"-container on path "/dfg"

Comment: Thanks alot @Markus . I finally figured it out as well along with all the modifiers. Also, I can't put my finger on whether the spaces between `Path:` and `/asd` is required or not or if it at all matters. Same thing with all the other modifiers.