# Rewriting the response header in traefik

Tags: traefik

I have a kubernetes cluster and I am using traefik ingress controller to route traffic to deployments inside the kubenetes cluster.

I am able to use `ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation to change the incoming request path to the one expected by the backend.
For example : `/star` is transformed to `/trek` by the rewrite target annotation and the request gets routed to `/trek` and backend processing is successful.

What I want to know is if there is a way to change response header so that `/trek` gets changed back to `/star`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get an answer to this? It looks like similar functionality is available in Apache Traffic Server: https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/admin-guide/plugins/header_rewrite.en.html, but would be good to have it in traefik

Comment: Ditched Traefik for HAProxy which lets you change response headers (or anything inside a response) as well. Used rspirep to replaced the Location header. Check this reference out: http://haproxy.tech-notes.net/6-http-header-manipulation/

Answer (score -1):

The functionality that does this is [modifiers](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#modifiers) and specifically `ReplacePath`. Here is [a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48546509/48639) with some examples.